Conditions Under Which a Complex Function Can Be Separated into Real and Imaginary Parts
This is about   how  and when complex valued functions  can be represented in terms of their real and imaginary components.As an example take  the well -known complex exponential function, $e^z$, which can be expressed as $u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$, where $u$ and $v$ are the real and imaginary parts of the function, respectively, and $z = x + iy$.Specifically ,$u(x,y)=e^x \cos y, \quad v(x,y)=e^x \sin(y)$
This leads  to question  about the possibility  of this representation. Specifically:

1.Is it possible to separate all complex functions into their real and imaginary parts in the form $f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$?

2.If not, under what conditions can a complex function be expressed in this way?
Thank you for insights and responses in advance.

You can always define $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ as the real and the imaginary part of $f(z)$.

Yes, it is always possible to decompose a complex function $-$ which is nothing else than a (dependent) complex variable $w = f(z)$ $-$ into its real and imaginary parts with the help of the usual relations, i.e.
$$
\begin{cases}
   u(x,y) = \dfrac{f(z) + \overline{f(z)}}{2} \\
   v(x,y) = \dfrac{f(z) - \overline{f(z)}}{2i} \\
\end{cases}
$$
